# Nuxt 3 - storing an access_token on the server side only

Tags: vue.js, auth0, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

On my Nuxt 3 app, the server-side api (/server/api) fetches data from a backend REST server.  The REST server requires an access token, which the server can get from Auth0 using client credentials.  The client secret can be stored as part of the Nuxt 3 private runtime config, and initialized with an environment variable.

But, where do I store the access token when it is received back from Auth0?  I don't want to store it on the client side for security reasons -- it's only used by the server-side fetching.  It appears that the Nuxt runtime config can only be initialized at app startup, not modified later -- and that access token will expire at some point and a new one obtained.

Pinia and useStorage are both client-side solutions.

Does Nuxt 3 have any kind of server-side modifiable storage that would be suitable?